# Regex - exclude "-" between numbers

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

In php I need to validate any number of positive and/or negative numbers from as input from textarea. Numbers can be float and will be separate by comma.

valid:

```
",,,66,,78.8,-89.8,,0.0,,3.14," or "," or "67,89,10,0876,,"
```

With help of regex101.com I've created this regex

```
^((-?\d+(\.\d+)?)|(,+))*$
```

and in php I have this code

```
if (preg_match("/^((-?\d+(\.\d+)?)|(,+))*$/", $text))
{
    echo "yes";
} else 
{
    echo "no";
}
```

And my problem is, that this regex also validate "-" and also extra "." among numbers.

This should be invalid:

```
",,67.8,89.8787,78-89,-8,07,,33.33.33,,,"
```

Can someone help how to improve this code?

Comment: Explode the string into an array of numbers then loop through the numbers and us is_numeric. http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php   http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
/^,*(-?\d*\.?\d+)?(?:,+\g<1>)*,*$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5JjSzH/1).

**Details**

- `^` - string start
- `,*` - 0+ commas
- `(-?\d*\.?\d+)?` - Optional capturing group 1 matching a float number (note: you may keep your original `\d+(?:\d+)?` if you do not want to match `.8` like floats)
- `(?:,+\g<1>)*` - 0+ repetitions of

  - `,+` - 1+ commas
  - `\g<1>` - Capturing group 1 pattern (this is a [subroutine call](https://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html) that is equal to `(?1)` and is used to repeat the first capturing group subpattern)
- `,*` - 0+ commas
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like that:

```
$my_string = ",,67.8,89.8787,78-89,-8,07,,33.33.33,,,";
$array = explode(",", $my_string);

foreach ($array as $value){
    if (preg_match("[regex_to_create]", $value))
    {
        echo "yes";
    } else 
    {
        echo "no";
    }
}
```

I prefer to explode the string, as the regex can be tricky sometimes with long strings.

Answer (score 0):

I modified you regex to `^(-?\d+(\.\d+)?,?)+$`

Now it will validate strings like

```
"66,78.8,-89.8,0.0,3.14"
```

but not

```
",,,66,,78.8,-89.8,,0.0,,3.14,"
```

nor

```
"67,89,10,0876,,"
```

See if this works for your case.

Here is the test: https://regex101.com/r/Ivah2H/1

Answer (score 0):

You could do this without Regular Expressions and with the help of `is_numeric` function:

```
$numbers = array_filter(explode(',', ',,67.8,-89.8787,7889,-8,07,,33.33.33,,,'));
$validate = true;
foreach ($numbers as $number) {
    if (!is_numeric($number)) {
        $validate = false;
        break;
    }
}

var_dump($validate); // false
```